# Statsmodels ARMA fit: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, statsmodels, autoregressive-models

I'm looking to build an ARMA model using the natural gas seasonal data downloadable [here](https://www.quandl.com/data/WSJ/NG_HH-Natural-Gas-Henry-Hub).

So:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/Path/To/WSJ-NG_HH.csv')
In [86]: df.head
Out[86]: 
<bound method DataFrame.head of            Date   Value
0    2015-10-31   2.100
1    2015-09-30   2.470
2    2015-08-31   2.680
3    2015-07-31   2.770
4    2015-06-30   2.770
```

Next I apply data = `np.asarray()` on the DataFrame:

```
data = np.asarray(df)
```

then intanstiate `ARMA`:

```
arma = sm.tsa.ARMA(data, order =(4,4))
```

When I try to fit:

```
results = arma.fit(full_output=False, disp=0)
```

I get:

```
/Users/Pyderman/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.pyc in fit(self, method, cov_type, cov_kwds, use_t, **kwargs)
    180                 self.rank = np_matrix_rank(np.diag(singular_values))
    181 
--> 182             beta = np.dot(self.pinv_wexog, self.wendog)
    183 
    184         elif method == "qr":

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

What must be done to allow the float values in the data to be processed?

Statsmodels version: 0.6.1

Comment: My guess is that date as separate column causes a problem. Maybe `data = np.asarray(df['Value'])` works. The error message is numpy that catches something strange, and doesn't tell more than something is wrong.